# jQuery/CSS - How do I select all the li display none in the document?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

jQuery/CSS - How do I select all the `<li style="display: none;">` in the document?

Comment: I dont understand y you selected answer which is given after 2 min and having same info which is provide in my answer....anyways..thanks

Comment: I tried yours, it didn't work.  Then I tried his and it did.  Then you put quotes around yours and made it like his.

Comment: that just typo error anyway thanks...not an issue.. for me point doesnt matter sharing info matter for me

Answer (score 52, accepted):

While the chosen answer works in your case, it's still doesn't answer the question. Same for the answers posted by other people, so I decided to write this anyway.

```
$('li[style*="display: none"]')
```

This will return a jQuery object representing a list of all the `<li>` elements in your document with a style property containing "display: none".

This is a different thing that finding all the hidden elements in the document.

Comment: Note that some browsers retain the exact format of the style attribute, so you would only find the elements where the style is written exactly like that, and not for example `<li style="display:none">`.

Comment: @Guffa: Right, but it depends on your needs. Given the question, it could be that the style is already present as an inline style. You could do a multiple attribute selector to specify both `display:none` and `display: none` anyway.

Comment: I like this answer because "li:hidden" will give you elements that might be hidden for others reason than "display: none". For example, a parent element might be hidden.

Comment: what does the * do here? first time I've seen it used

Comment: @artworkjpm it checks that the string "display: none" is contained somewhere in the style attribute.

Answer (score 10):

There is a selector to find hidden elements:

```
$('li:hidden')
```

Note that this finds all `li` elements that are not visible, not only because they have the style `display:none` applied to them. The element could be hidden for example by setting their height to zero, or hiding the parent element.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$("li").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" })
```

Comment: -1 because the selector is already avaialbe y to repeate by creating this kind of code

Comment: I didn't know it was available. My bad. Just trying to help out.

Comment: your suggested answer finds all hidden elements though, not just display = none.

Answer (score 4):

`$('li:hidden')` - Try as per jquery document it will work

Fore more dtail - [**:hidden Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

```
$("li").not(":visible")
```

or

```
$("li:hidden")
```

then do everything inline or use `.each()` to loop through all.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.3.2, an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0. What does this change mean? It means that if your element’s CSS display is “none”, or any of its parent/ancestor element’s display is “none”, or if the element’s width is 0 and the element’s height is 0 then an element will be reported as hidden.
See here: http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/

Example:

This means the **li** element is recognized as hidden only if you have a parent that has **display: none** style:

```
$("li:hidden")
```